"Ils n'ont pas obtenu DE majorité." Is it not the negation of "ils ont obtenu LA majorité"?
From this news

Alors si ces deux motions n'ont pas obtenu de majorité.

Is it correct to think that de is used following the rule that indefinite articles of direct objects become de in negative sentences?
My dictionary only has examples using a definite article in similar expressions: avoir la majorité. Are both avoir/obtenir la/une majorité acceptable as mentioned in this question (even in cases where there is no restrictive phrase (de ...) after majorité?

Does this answer your question? Why is “de” used in “il n'y a pas de bus direct”?

@guillaume31 No, my question rather boils down to  if obtenir une majorité is idiomatic because logically obtenir la majorité looks correct.

Not a duplicate, although you wouldn't guess from the original title alone. I tried to fix that, feel free to improve.

The negation of ils ont obtenu la majorité is ils n'ont pas obtenu la majorité.
Ils n'ont pas obtenu de majorité is the negation of ils ont obtenu une majorité [Laquelle ? La majorité absolue/...].
All of these sentences are slightly ambiguous if the kind of majority isn't specified. The last one is rarely used without specifying it, e.g.:

Ils ont obtenu une majorité des suffrages.
Ils ont obtenu une majorité de 10 voix. (Here la majorité wouldn't work.)
Ils ont obtenu une majorité des deux tiers.
Ils ont obtenu une majorité de blocage.

but

Ils ont obtenu la majorité requise. (une majorité wouldn't work.)


une majorité requise wouldn't work, but "une majorité nécessaire* or une majorité absolue (even though la would work better) or une majorité simple would.
